# Can't install wicd on Linux Mint Cinnamon 20: Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: wicd-daemon (=1.7.4+tb2-5)

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, wicd

Due to using Linux Mint Cinnamon 20, Wicd isn't available. 
It was available in earlier versions of Linux Mint.

I've tried to type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Nothing is indicating that wicd is in the system.
So I went to wicd official website. I followed the instructions to the best of my abilities, with no results.

Also downloaded package from pkgs.org.
Install package button is grayed out

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: wicd-daemon (=1.7.4+tb2-5)
```

This is likely because I'm using Linux 20.

I've been stuck for 4 days. 
How can I get past this?

Answer (score 2):

`wicd` was removed from Debian unstable on [22 August 2020](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wicd).  If we look at the [release-critical bugs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=no&pend-exc=pending-fixed&pend-exc=fixed&pend-exc=done&sev-inc=critical&sev-inc=grave&sev-inc=serious&repeatmerged=no&src=wicd) of `wicd`, we see three big ones:

- [#956159](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=956159) Package depends on python-glade2, python-gtk2, which are no longer in sid
- [#946380](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=946380) wicd-gtk does not find gtk modules
- [#885140](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=885140) wicd: Depends on unmaintained pygtk

Debian has been in the process of removing python2 and all packages which depend on it.  That includes things like `python-glade2`.  Often we'd be able to switch the dependency to `python3-glade2`, but in the case of glade and gtk, there are no python3 versions and there will never be.  Instead [gnome has replaced this library](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting) with gobject-introspection.  That means things which were written for glade need to be rewritten or ported.

`wicd`'s latest version (1.7.4) was uploaded to Debian in 2016 and has only been patched by the maintainer since then.  If I look at the [upstream repository](https://launchpad.net/wicd/+download) linked in the Debian [copyright file](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/w/wicd/copyright-1.7.2.4-4.1), I see that the original author hasn't touched the package since 2012.

I recommend finding an alternative package instead of holding your breath for it to be modernized.